# Good practices for handling project over to another developer

Tags: project-management

What are some good procedures to follow when handing a project to another developer, in cases of when the original developer will still be around for a couple of months to aid in the transition? Let's assume a medium-sized web application if a concrete example is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been on both ends.  Taking over a code base and handing it off.

**You should:**

- Identify areas that aren't completely
  obvious.  So, if you have a directory
  called "xml" but all your flash
  object get their data from
  "flash/swfs/xml" you should document
  that.
- Identify parts of the database which
  are no longer in use.  If there are
  tables that simply have no use
  anymore.
- Identify areas of concern such as
  speed/performance of certain pages.
- If you have some really backwards
  logic on certain pages, explain why,
  if it's not been commented in the
  code directly.
- Any third party vendors should be
  identified along with their cost and
  use on the site.  So if you're using
  a delivery network to stream your
  flash videos, definitely let that be
  known.
- If you have pages still in the
  project, but aren't being used
  anymore, identify them, or simply
  remove them.
- If you know for a fact that your
  database was poorly designed,
  contains no constraints or indexes
  and has no primary keys on many
  tables, mention it.  It will let the
  new developer know they need to
  optimize the database.
- If you hardcoded e-mail addresses
  within the code and didn't put them
  in .config files, identify that as
  well.

I'm sure there are more but there are things I wish were brought to my attention on a project I had taken over at one point.

Answer (score 3):

As a junior developer, I have gotten several projects assigned to me for maintainance that were written by others. I believe the easiest projects to continue are the ones where the code is clean and well documented (meaningful var names and formatting as well), the archetecture is relatively strightfoward, and the developer took some time to write some notes on the use of his components. In Java this would include class-level javadoc; in other languages it may include a header at the top of the source code.

Also, if the original developer is available and open to questions, it makes learning the archetecture much simpler - no puzzling out what he was thinking.

Comment: +1 - I've been there as I'm sure we all have.  It's almost like a right of passage -- "here ya go kid, have fun.. muahahaha"

Answer (score 1):

If you have written your code from the start so that it is sensibly architected and fairly simple to understand, and provided adequate documentation, transitional problems should be minimal.

But training is always nice.

Comment: I don't think I've ever taken over a project that was so well put together that no explaining was required.  It could happen though, I think.

Answer (score 1):

For anything that requires a build environment (certain compiler, 3rd-party libraries, opensource libraries, paths, etc.,), have the original developer sit down with the new developer, at the new developer's workstation, and walk through the process of making a simple change, committing to the source control, building, smoke test, etc.. Lots of times projects that are out of the mainstream may have odd procedures for testing, or they may come from an unfamiliar repository branch, may need a specific compiler version, libraries, etc.. Bugs may be tracked differently, it may require specific logins or endpoints for testing, etc..  By walking the new dev through the process, on their workstation, you'll uncover all of those issues, saving the new dev lots of frustration.